# I am unable to see the components inside my frame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

Hi I'm coding an alarm application.
I have a snooze class which gets called when the alarm sounds. It used to work fine before using JMF.But after using JMF I see only the outer frame of my snooze UI.

I tried starting a new thread for the class but got the same result. I'm pasting here code of the classes in which I think the problem is in.

Please help me solve the problem.

**IsTime class. Which checks whether it is the time to sound alarm. **

```
 package alarm;  
 import java.util.Calendar;  
 import java.util.GregorianCalendar;  

 public class IsTime {  
int hrs;  
int min;  
int sec;  
GregorianCalendar clk=new GregorianCalendar();  
Calendar gtl= Calendar.getInstance();  
    mp3 mix=new mp3();  
public void makeReady(int h,int m,int s,String ampm){  
    Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();  
    c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,h);  
    c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);  
    c1.set(Calendar.SECOND,s);  
    if("PM".equals(ampm)){  
        c1.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);  
        if(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.AM_PM)==Calendar.PM){  
            System.out.println("now is pm");  
            if(c1.after(Calendar.getInstance())){  
                check(c1);  
            }  
            c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)+1);  
            check(c1);  
        }  
    }  
    if(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.AM_PM)==Calendar.AM){  
            System.out.println("now is am");  
            if(c1.after(Calendar.getInstance())){  
                check(c1);  
            }  
            c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)+1);  
            check(c1);  
        }  
    if(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.AM_PM)==Calendar.PM){  
        c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)+1);  
        check(c1);  
    }  
}  
public void check(Calendar ch){  
        System.out.println("got to check");  
        System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));  
        System.out.println(ch.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));  
        while(!(Calendar.getInstance().after(ch))){  
        }  
    Snooze snz=new Snooze();  
            snz.start();  
            mix.start();  
    }  
public void makeReady(int mis){  
        Calendar sz=Calendar.getInstance();  
        sz.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
        sz.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE)+mis);  
        check(sz);  
    }  
    }
```

**Media class which plays song when it is time **

```
     package alarm;  
import java.awt.Button;  
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;  
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;  
import javax.media.*;  
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.URL;  
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;  

class mp3 extends Thread  
{  
private URL url;  
private MediaLocator mediaLocator;  
private Player playMP3;  
static String mp3;  
static String mp4;  
public mp3()  
{  
try{  
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));  
    System.out.println("before"+mp3);  
    if(System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Linux")){  
        mp4="file://".concat(mp3);  
    }  
    else{  
    mp4="file:///".concat(mp3);  
    }  
    System.out.println(mp4);  
   this.url = new URL(mp4);  
   }catch(java.net.MalformedURLException e)  
      {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}  
}  
public void run()  
{  
try{  
    System.out.println(url);  
   mediaLocator = new MediaLocator(url);       
   playMP3 = Manager.createPlayer(mediaLocator);  
    }catch(java.io.IOException e)  
      {System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
    }catch(javax.media.NoPlayerException e)  
      {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}  
playMP3.addControllerListener(new ControllerListener()  
  {  
  public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent e)  
     {  
     if (e instanceof EndOfMediaEvent)  
         {  
         playMP3.stop();  
         playMP3.close();  
         }  
     }  
  }  
 );  
 playMP3.realize();  
 playMP3.start();  
 }   
}
```

**Snooze class where the real problem is **

```
     package alarm;  
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;  
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;  
import javax.swing.JButton;  
import javax.swing.JComboBox;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;  
import javax.swing.JLabel;  
public class Snooze extends Thread implements ActionListener{  
    JFrame sozef=new JFrame("Snooze");  
    JLabel tl=new JLabel("After");  
    JLabel ml=new JLabel("mins");  
    JComboBox tiec=new JComboBox();  
    JButton soo=new JButton("Snooze");  
    JButton stp=new JButton("Stop");  
        mp3 mi=new mp3();  
        Snooze sz;  
        public void run(){  
            sozef.setSize(500,700);  
        sozef.setLayout(null);  
        tl.setBounds(50,50,50,50);  
        tiec.setBounds(50,90,50,30);  
        ml.setBounds(120,90,50,50);  
        soo.setBounds(50,130,90,30);  
        stp.setBounds(50, 170, 90, 30);  
        JcAdd(tiec);  
        sozef.add(tl);  
        sozef.add(tiec);  
        sozef.add(ml);  
        sozef.add(soo);  
        sozef.add(stp);  
        soo.addActionListener(this);  
        sozef.setVisible(true);  
        sozef.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        }  
    void JcAdd(JComboBox jc){  
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)  
            jc.addItem(Integer.toString(i));  
    }  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {  
        if(arg0.getSource()==soo){  
        int ma=Integer.parseInt(tiec.getSelectedItem().toString());  
        mi.stop();  
        IsTime sz=new IsTime();  
        sz.makeReady(ma);  
        }  
        mi.stop();  
    }  
}  ![this is the frame I see when the snooze is being called][1]
```

Comment: `setLayout(null);`  I do not need to see any more than that to realize this app. has serious problems.  Use layouts with padding and borders, for a much better behaved GUI.   For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: But Mr. Andrew Thompson this GUI worked independently it is in the combination of Media code I think it got a problem

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to implement a delay:

```
while(!(Calendar.getInstance().after(ch))){  
}
```

In fact, it's going to cause serious problems.

Try calculating the number of milliseconds between your target date and the current time, and passing that value to `Thread.sleep`.  Your computer's case fans will thank you.  And it may very well be the case that your busy loop is starving the AWT event thread, thus preventing your frame from showing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I understood the problem with the statement. I will try the Thread.sleep and post post what happened